# Why publish raise error on hosting site but work fine in local IIS

Tags: .net, publish, nopcommerce

Start working on no-commerce, Sorry for the basic question, want to deploy my no-pcommerce-4 application on hosting(https://www.smarterasp.net/)show me below error but same application deploy on local IIS work fine. Have not idea why the error raise. What to do?

[image]

Comment: "Have not idea why the error raise" - you'll need to find this out. Are there any logs available on your host? If there's really no information then you should contact the host and ask them to look at their logs or the server's event log, but I'd be surprised if you didn't have access to the IIS logs at least. And are those the right versions of the framework and core that you're using, i.e. it's not going to be a missing dependency or failure to load because of the wrong .NET version?

Comment: @Rup thanks for your reply, will you please provide a list, that needs to be installed in deployment server, Attachment picture contains information about my hosting environment, maybe miss something. In hosting server application not start so log file not write.

Comment: Visual Studio should be able to package up everything you need. Yes, I can see the details of your hosting environment: have you built your code for that environment? And I mean IIS's logs and the event logs, which it will write even before your application starts, and will hopefully contain the exception that caused the application to not start.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this error. Most of the time is happening because of missing of core sdk and DotNetCore windows hosting. You also need to make sure that all files have read and write access permissions.

Nopcommerce also logs the startup task. You can see the exact error there. To enable this logging you need to enable stdoutLogEnabled from the web.config stdoutLogEnabled="true". Then you will able to see the reason for the error under the Logs folder of the site at SmartASP.NET.

You must make sure that core sdk and DotNetCore windows hosting are available at the server.

Answer (score 0):

smarterasp hosting already provide you inbuilt application of nopcommerce. you just need to install it on single click.

if you want to see the error then you just need to enable **stdoutLogEnabled="false"** into web.config file. and provide full write/read permision to your whole project folder and then you can check error log into log folder.

and also change into web.config file to get actual error

```
<aspNetCore .....>
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
```